# Tablix Textbox Border Rendering with 2 pt on the sides

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have created and SSRS report.  I have a text box for my Tablix header.  I set the border to 1pt solid black, but the sides are rendering with 2pts when I convert to pdf. Is this just how my machine renders or is there a way to fix this? The team I am creating this report for keep complaining that the borders are uneven but I'm not sure how to make sure they render evenly. [image: image of border]

Comment: Is there a shadow on the textbox?  The missing piece in the corner makes it look like this isn't the border itself.

Comment: Is the tablix inside of a rectangle with a border?  Typically this sort of thing can happen most often with mismatched, nested objects such as a tablix in a rectangle or the inverse.

Comment: there is no shadow, this is how the textbox renders when converting to pdf.  When I zoom-in in report designer it shows one pixels around the perimeter as expected.

Comment: @Steve-o169, this is a textbox border inside of a tablix.  There is no rectangle around the tablix.